# Transferring tokens to user using google cloud functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, ethereum, web3js

I am transferring token to the User's wallet when they create an account. For that, I am using google cloud functions.

Here, on the account creation event, tokens will get transferred to the address. My cloud function is working fine but the token transfer function is not getting triggered. Here is the code-

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var Web3 = require('web3');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);      
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
var Personal = require('web3-eth-personal')
var personal = new Personal(Personal.givenProvider)
var ABI = [{'contract ABI'}]
var contract =new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, '0xF62E0..fd44fC931571ae957')

exports.newUser = (event, callback) => {
    const triggerResource = event.resource;
    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount("0xc..9050f547", "password", 60, (unlock) => {
        contract.methods.transfer('0x4..bB7d982D8A8632e', 2).
        send({
            from: '0xC3Fe4...0F547',
            gas: 210000
        }, (error, txhash) => {
            if (!error && txhash) {
                console.log(triggerResource);
            }
        });
    })
    callback();
};
```

I have deployed the contract on a private network.

Comment: I've passed your code through https://beautifier.io/ to make it more readable. Please do this yourself next time, as having well formatted code in your question make it much more likely that somebody will see the problem and answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `send()` method you call seems to be asynchronous, but you've calling the callback before it has finished. To fix this, move the call to `callback()` in to the block of code that runs after `send()` is done:

```
exports.newUser = (event, callback) => {
    const triggerResource = event.resource;
    web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount("0xc..9050f547", "password", 60, (unlock) => {
        contract.methods.transfer('0x4..bB7d982D8A8632e', 2).
        send({
            from: '0xC3Fe4...0F547',
            gas: 210000
        }, (error, txhash) => {
            if (!error && txhash) {
                console.log(triggerResource);
            }
            callback(error);
        });
    })
};
```

You'll see that the code now also passes the `error` into the callback, which means it'll show up in your Cloud Functions logs.

Comment: Nothing happened. My cloud function is working fine but the token transfer function is not getting triggered.